# Proof of PCP theorem

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, probabilistic-algorithms

I am reading the proof of PCP theorem in [Proof Verication and Hardness of Approximation Problems](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/papers/1992/almss-conf.pdf). The following paragraph appears in section 3 (page 4), *"Outline of the Proof of the Main Theorem"*.

> The results of these sections show that $NP \subset OPT (poly(n), 1)$ (Theorem 5) and $NP \subset OPT (\log n, poly \log n)$ (Theorem 8). Theorems 9 and 10 show that the recursion idea applies to these proof systems, and in particular shows the following:
>
> 1. $OPT (f (n), g(n)) \subset OPT (f (n) + O(\log g(n)), (\log g(n))^{O(1)} )$ and
> 2. $OPT (f (n), g(n)) \subset OPT (f (n) + (g(n))^{O(1)} , 1)$.
>
> This allows us to conclude that $NP \subset OPT (\log n, poly \log \log n)$ (**by composing** two $OPT (\log n, poly \log n)$ proof systems) and then **by composing** this system with the $OPT (poly(n), 1)$ proof system we obtain $OPT (\log n, 1)$ proof system for $NP$.

**Edit.** Composition of verifiers is defined in [Probabilistic Checking of Proofs: A New Characterization of NP](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/pcp/AS.pdf)  section 3 (page 13) *"Normal Form Verifiers and Their Use in Composition"*.

> Let $r, q, s, t$ be any functions defined on the natural integers. Suppose there is a normal-form verifier $V_2$ that is $(r(n), s(n), q(n), t(n))$-constrained. Then, for all functions $R, Q, S, T$, $$RPCP(R(n), S(n), Q(n), T(n)) \subseteq \\RPCP(R(n) + r(\tau), s(\tau), Q(n) + q(\tau), Q(n)t(\tau))$$ where $\tau$ is a shorthand for $O((T(n))^2)$.

Where $RPCP(r, s, q, t)$ is a $PCP(r, s \cdot q)$ which takes $t$ time to accept of reject *after* reading the $s \cdot q$ bits.

I still don't see how this composition works. Is $OPT(r, q) = RPCP(r, q, 1, q)$ and a normal form verifier? In that case it seems to work, but then just composing $OPT(poly(n), 1)$ with $OPT(\log n, poly \log n)$ is enough, so why bother with $OPT(\log n, poly \log \log n)$ or relations $1.$ and $2.$?

Comment: Did you check the references given in 1.2, in particular [AS92]?

Comment: Check Arora's thesis, Lemma 3.1 on page 20. (Link: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/thesis.pdf)

Comment: Did you find your answer in these references?

Comment: @Raphael, partly. I added a more specific question with an **edit**.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Did you see the updated question?

Comment: @Raphael I doubt that an answer would be of any help at this time. Since all I can do is read the papers and answer the question, I think that Karolis is in a better position to answer the question, assuming that by now the difficulty has been cleared up.